# Let A be a real square matrix satisfying $A^5 = 0. $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a real square matrix satisfying $A^5 = 0. $

(A) Show that the matrix I - A is invertible.

(B)  If B is an invertible matrix, is B - A also invertible?

for first one Since (A) since $A^5=0 $ then 00 is the only possible eigenvalue of A  In particular 1  is not an eigenvalue, ie, A+I is injective this implies  A+I is invertiable

what about (B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: ..is A satisfies A^5=0

Comment: What is $A^2 $?

Comment: ....A^2=0,,, but sorry i dont understand

Comment: Then $A^5=0A^3$.

Answer (score 0):

As $A^5=0$ so all the eigen values are $0$, write in diagonal form then subtract $I-A$,  as $I$ is invertable $I-A$ is also and $B-A$ is also